# Restrict same user to login from other PC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning about ASP.NET Identity and I want to restrict same user to login on different PC (by IP address ), I can do it by Session but with ASP.NET Identity I need a suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an IP Address of the user by `Request.UserHostAddress`. If you are on a localhost server then the result will be `::1` because that is the IPv6 result of a localhost.

You can save the IP Address to the user by adding user data to the IdentityModel class. e.g.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string IP { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you could save the IP address to the users profile by requesting their IP on sign up. You can do this by changing the data that is saved to the DB on sign up. Do this in the Account controller Register method.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,
IP = Request.UserHostAddress };
```

Once that's done, you can change the login method to something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
    var IP = Request.UserHostAddress;

    if (IP != user.IP)
    {
        result = SignInStatus.Failure;
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Log in with your original computer");
        return View(model);
    }

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");

        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

It should be done. Don't forget to run `update-database` in the package-manager console.